# Programming a bare ATSAMD21E18A, no external oscillator

Tags: microcontroller, programming, bootloader

EDIT: I got this working, seems that the uC is sensitive to bypass caps. I had caps on my solderless breadboard and decided to solder on some surface caps right at the pins on the breakout board. That seemed to do the trick.

I have a standalone ATSAMD21E18A on a breakout board that I'm trying to flash. I've followed the steps [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/how-to-program-samd-bootloaders/programming-the-bootloader-with-atmel-studio), to burn the bootloader. It looks like it took just fine. Then, it seems like I can flash the standalone chip over the jlink interface but then it just does nothing.

I've successfully done this process with a [Trinket M0](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3500) and I'm using PlatformIO to do step-through debugging using jlink. I've compared the fuses of each and I had a hunch that the standalone chip isn't using the internal oscillator for some reason. Am I wrong? How can I confirm that the internal oscillator is being used?

I burn the [Trinket M0 bootloader](https://github.com/adafruit/uf2-samdx1/releases/download/v3.13.0/bootloader-trinket_m0-v3.13.0.bin) on both the bare ATSAMD21E18A and Trinket M0. Trinket works, the bare ATSAMD21E18A doesn't. I've tried this now on 3 different ATSAMD21E18As with the same result. What am I missing?

[image: Bare ATSAMD21E18A]

[image: Trinket M0]

Comment: Do you have the required bypass caps connected?

Comment: I do. I actually wired it just like the Trinket M0, https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/045/723/original/adafruit_products_schem.png?1503525048